# Visual Studio: "Is not a Win32 application" error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm following a tutorial to set up a particular Visual Studio project which gives me the following instructions:

[image: See this]

It also adds that I should build the project in Release32 mode, done by replacing Debug with Release, and then choosing x86 or Win32.

However, doing all of this, the project does not build, but rather throws the error "Is not a Win32 application".

How do I solve this?

Comment: ***"Is not a Win32 application*** then ***How do I solve this?*** Nothing to solve this is a user error. You can't run a dll by itself. You get the error because you attempted to do so.

Comment: @drescherjm Are you sure? The OP says "the project does not build, but rather..."

Comment: I think it built fine but the user clicked the debug / play button to build and debug.

Comment: Then did you get a compiler error in the Output Tab? The error message you say is what happens if you try to run (or debug) a target / project that is not executable.

Comment: The part "_builds an application with the extension".dll"._" Is incorrect and misleading.  A DLL is not an application, it is a library of code that can be used by an application.  You cannot run it.  Are you sure it does not build?  What does the log say?  You need to use the _build_, rather then the _build & run_ command.

Comment: In your environment options, you can tell the debugger which program to start and then browse and specify Excel.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DLLs: Dynamic Link Libraries

These are ***NOT*** code that can be run on there own - only an executable can be run (well, an app on windows - there may also be others like VBS etc.)

You can, however, call a DLL import in build and then use the code from the dll as normal library.

The header file:

```
#pragma once  

#ifdef DLLEXAMPLE_EXPORTS  
#define DLLEXAMPLE_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define DLLEXAMPLE_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif
```

The source file:

```
#include <headerfile>
```

Then, build using the VS cli: `cl /EHsc /DLLEXAMPLE_EXPORTS /LD <source file>` or just build in VS

You will then be able to reference it by doing (after you've filled out all of the info for the win32 console app but not creating it;

- go to end solution control - dropdown
- add to solution
- create solution
- solution explorer - references
- tick the reference

*to add the folder of the header file - work anywhere it's built*

- solution properties/config props/general/Add inc dirs/edit/put the path to the header file's directory location in the top field
- add
- go back through each window saving changes where possible

This should now work by including the header file in your source.